# CSS flip card but not back effect

Tags: javascript, css

I find a sample for use a card flip: https://codepen.io/mondal10/pen/WNNEvjV

Th effect 'Front' to 'Back' is good but **I want the same effect 'Back' to 'Front' (not revert)**

the code add/remove this class by a `classList.toggle`:

**CSS:**

```
.card.is-flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

**javascript:**

```
[...cards].forEach((card)=>{
  card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scene scene--card">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the effect 'Front' to 'Back' is transform ... and effect 'Back' to 'Front' is inverse

Comment: @j08691, sorry, I fix the link just now

Comment: You need to provide the [mre] in the question itself, not rely on external sites like codepen.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I add now javascript part but the css important code is all ready in this post

Comment: It is not a [mre] (e.g. there is no HTML in your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your animation right now only uses js to toggle a class which sets the rotate to 180, then removes it returning to 0deg rotation. If you want to continue rotating in the initial direction, you need to continuously increase the degrees rotated. I do this by changing the css to use css variables, then use js to remember the current rotation for that card, and set it to continuously increase.

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

[...cards].forEach((card)=>{
  let y = 0;
  card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle("is-flipped");
    y -= 180;
    card.style.setProperty(
      "--y",
      `${y}deg`
    ); 
  });
});
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.scene {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
/*   border: 1px solid #CCC; */
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(var(--x, 0)) rotateY(var(--y, 0));
}

.card.is-flipped {
  --x: -100%;
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: crimson;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: slateblue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene scene--card">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scene scene--card">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Click card to flip.</p>
```

Comment: The visual rendering is almost good. There is still a difference between the two cases, the first goes towards the depth and the second towards the front.